# pushing envelop Using WSDL, SOAP and C#

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

This is my first time even looking at web services, I've searched around and couldn't find exactly what I wanted to know.

I need to develop a windows service which connects to a webservice that uses SOAP and has a WSDL, all I have to go with is what the xml envelope looks like and a long http string that I'm told is the WSDL. In Visual Studio you can use the WSDL to create an interface for that webservice and then what? I believe I now need to "push" the envelope but I have got no clue how to do that. In the code bellow the envelope is given the name BONUS_TABLE and each envelope item is put into ZCIR_BOIN_STRUCTURE_IN[] as far as I understand.

so my question is, am I even doing this right? if not then how am I meant to do this? but if I am on the right path then what do I do to "push" the envelope.

```
    PaymentInterface.BONUS_PAYMENTS_PUSH Client = new PaymentInterface.BONUS_PAYMENTS_PUSH();
    PaymentInterface.BONUS_PAYMENTS_PUSHRequest request = new PaymentInterface.BONUS_PAYMENTS_PUSHRequest();
    PaymentInterface.BONUS_PAYMENTS_PUSHResponse response = new PaymentInterface.BONUS_PAYMENTS_PUSHResponse();

    PaymentInterface.ZCIR_BOIN_STRUCTURE_IN[] items;
    public void SendPayments()
    {
        DataTable dtPayments = loadPayments();
        items = new PaymentInterface.ZCIR_BOIN_STRUCTURE_IN[dtPayments.Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < dtPayments.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            items[i].INDNUMB = dtPayments.Rows[i]["IndustryNo"].ToString();
            items[i].WAGETYPE = dtPayments.Rows[i]["RunType"].ToString();
            items[i].PAY_AMOUNT = Convert.ToDecimal(dtPayments.Rows[i]["Amount"]);
            items[i].DATECHANGED = dtPayments.Rows[i]["RunDate"].ToString();
        }

        Client.BONUS_TABLE = items;
        // send the payments to the webservice?            
    }
```